# LINQ select table without any references

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Is there a way to only select one table with any references?

Because with my current code the `DataContext` returns a `Types` object. But LINQ adds a property on it called `campaign` and in that property there are **all other references**. So i takes **forever** when i am requesting data from my restapi controller, cause it needs to load **all references**. But i only want the Table i was asking for.

Current code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Typs")]
public IHttpActionResult Typs()
{
   crmDataContext crmDC = new crmDataContext();
   jsSettings = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

   return Json(crmDC.Typs), jsSettings);
}
```

Typs propertys that i have defined in my database

```
public class Typs 
{
   public int id;
   public string text;
}
```

Typs propertys that linq made for my c# code

```
public class Typs 
{
   public int id;
   public string text;
   public campaign campaign;
}
```

Comment: Welcome!  Check out _[Capitalization Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions)_ during your coffee break ;)

Comment: This has nothing to do with plain Linq. My best guess is you are using Linq-To-Sql. Maybe it's entity framework, feel free to add appropriate tags

Answer (score 1):

It does'nt make sense. You must used Include() or explicit loading `.Collection(p => p.Posts).Load();` otherwise related entities are not loaded.

Futhermore you dont need to add `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;` if you are not goind to load related entities which in turns references the table itself.